# How can i create many replicators to the sync gateway?

Tags: java, android

I have created one replicator with pull and push options, but the problem is that i need to get some documents from the Couchbase server without having the possibility of pushing. Can anyone help me with this issue ?
Note: I am using couchbase lite 2.5, couchbase server 6.0 and sync gateway 2.5

My current replicator for push and pull

```
public static void startPushAndPullReplicationForCurrentUser(String username, String password) {
    Log.e("Replication", "startPushAndPullReplicationForCurrentUser");
    URI url = null;
    try {
        url = new URI(mSyncGatewayEndpoint);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ReplicatorConfiguration config = new ReplicatorConfiguration(database, new URLEndpoint(url));
    config.setReplicatorType(ReplicatorConfiguration.ReplicatorType.PUSH_AND_PULL);
    config.setContinuous(true);
    config.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator(username, password));

    Replicator replicator = new Replicator(config);
    replicator.addChangeListener(new ReplicatorChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ReplicatorChange change) {

            if (change.getReplicator().getStatus().getActivityLevel().equals(Replicator.ActivityLevel.IDLE)) {

                Log.e("Replication Comp Log", "Schedular Completed");

            }
            if (change.getReplicator().getStatus().getActivityLevel().equals(Replicator.ActivityLevel.STOPPED)
                    || change.getReplicator().getStatus().getActivityLevel().equals(Replicator.ActivityLevel.OFFLINE)) {
                // stopReplication();
                Log.e("Rep schedular  Log", "ReplicationTag Stopped");
            }
        }
    });
    replicator.start();
}
```

all the database is attached to the push and pull replicator, but that is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a replicator to not push, use     `config.setReplicatorType(ReplicatorConfiguration.ReplicatorType.PULL);` instead of PUSH_AND_PULL.  We use this on my project where we want the server to validate records before pushing to the db (validation is too complex for their simple validation mechanism-  it requires us to fetch other records, which that mechanism doesn't allow).

There is no way to do bidirectional syncing on some docs but unidirectional on others.  Its an all or nothing setting.  What you can do if you need that though is to put everything to PULL, and when you change a document you'd want to push, manually push it to the server via your own endpoint or a direct sync gateway API call.  This does risk getting the dbs out of sync though, especially if offline on documents frequently changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.5, you can use [replication filters](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.5/java.html#replication-filters) to do just that. 
In your case,  set up a push-pull replicator and define a push replication filter to filter out documents that you do not want to push up (local only).